# airodump-ng is malfunctioning

Tags: linux, vmware, wifi

I'm on Kali-linux 32 bits on Oracle VM VirtualBox, and I have this problem with airodump-ng,

I got my wireless card's interface name, put it into monitoring mode with airmon-ng command, but when I attempt to locate the available wireless networks nearby, the airodump-ng tool displays ZERO access points:

[image]

I just want to add that the wlan interface didn't show up at first, so I downloaded and installed compat wireless.

Answer (score 0):

the virtual box cannot virtualize the Wifi card, so u need an externe network adapter able to be switched to monitoring mode, u can see at wiki-linux. or install it on your physical machine if your network adapter is compatible.

Comment: Please provide some additional details in your answer.  Simply referring to a wiki does not help the OP as much as an actual person explaining the issue, nor does it help StackExchange's mission of providing a standalone compendium of knowledge.

Comment: Well unfortunately for the moment the only wifi adapter I got is defective, I will try your proposition later.. I'm going to try the command on the distribution installed in my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check if your wireless adapter is compatible with kali-linux. You can check [here](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/buy-best-wireless-network-adapter-for-wi-fi-hacking-2017-0178550/) for suggested wireless adapter.

For my case i am using TP-link wn722n wireless adapter which work fine with kali linux. You can simply switch the wireless interface to monitor mode by using the command below without using airmon-ng command.

```
Iwconfig [Interface name] mode monitor
```

Answer (score -1):

•   First of all, you need configure the Oracle VM: File – Settings – Proxy – select Direct Connection to Internet

•   Then you configure your Kali Linux VM: plug your network adapter in USB – go to Settings – in Net select Bridge mode – in USB you must add your network adapter – then edit the filter, Remote must be No

•   Then, VERY IMPORTANT, UNPLUG YOUR NETWORK ADAPTER FROM USB

•   After that star you start your Kali Linux VM

•   After the Kali Linux being ready, then, just then, PLUG YOUR NETWORK ADAPTER IN USB

•   In this point you are going to listen 2 noises, one for the connection in the host e other for the connection in VM

•   You can check the status in Devices – USB, you must see your network adapter already selected

•   Try the airodump routine, it has good chances to work